# how to properly secure php app, so it won't bug out on non-ideal data

Tags: php

so I want to properly secure my app from crashes on "udefined indexes". Say that article exists but is listed in nonexistant category, or its author is out of system (basically missing id), or doesn't have any tags (missing list of tags)...

My problem is that whilst I can check for every id and array everywhere (like check for existing author everywhere where I use author...), I don't really want to do that and I am hoping for some simpler/more practical solutions, or some effective workflows/best practices.

My primary issue is that I don't even know how to label this problem, so I have very hard time googling anything about that, finding some tutorials and so on...

example:

```
$this->article = $this->data->articles( $this->articleId);
$this->author = $this->data->authorGet($this->article['article_user_id']);
```

This crashes if article isn't found (and obviously, I can check it here, but I don't want to do that on every single line in my system, or forget it somewhere and have a bug)

Comment: So, can you show us some code where you get that error?

Comment: I have added an example

Comment: So, what crashes? What is the underlying code? We can't help you if you don't show us the specific code that isn't working...

Comment: I don't want help with these exact lines of code... If I get an article, it will be an array and articleuserid will exist there. If I don't, article will be null and index wont exist (or index will point to non existant author).I am asking if I have to check for that everywhere or if I can have some better ways of going about it... in this example, I dont care that I didnt find author,I would still like to show article and not crash on that, but again I dont want to check for that on every line of code. I am looking for general solutions, workflows architectures etc. that take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Data_Validation) I get the feeling, that I have to do it on each and every place separately, maybe integrate some of the stuff in code (say author of article could be part of article itself and article db loading would be "no author protected").